# Craftbook Collect: Sort enchanted Books/Items

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server, minecraft-bukkit

Is there a way to sort enchanted Book with Craftbook?

With `/iinfo` I get IDs like the following:

```
403#G
403#4i
403#2L
```

I simply tried to use this as ID, but it didn't work (collected just all). I googled around and tried other possibilities, but none of them worked.

```
403:34 --> is of enchantment
403;unbreaking --> Name of enchantment corresponding to Craftbooks item syntax
```

At least I heard there is no way. Is this true? Or is there a way I can't see? Or maybe an other way?

PS: I play on a Server, so the possibilities are maybe in a short range.

Note: The question is also for Items.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Meanwhile a friend reasked this question to the developer directly. The answer is that its not possible **AND** that the `/iinfo` data isn't a valid ID.

So, answer is short: not possible

Answer (score 0):

Just to update old information. This has been possible since my PR back in Nov 2016 https://github.com/EngineHub/CraftBook/pull/197

Use the Sorter IC (MC1229) to sort enchanted books. ;)

Also worth mentioning is a new PR I did just this morning that adds even more control over the Sorter IC. https://github.com/EngineHub/CraftBook/pull/204