# Craftbook - Sort Potions

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server, minecraft-bukkit

I think it's possibly something like a duplicate of my other question [Craftbook Collect: Sort enchanted Books/Items](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/259273/craftbook-collect-sort-enchanted-books-items)

But I have a similar question about how to sort potions or if it is possible.
The syntax for potions seems to differ from enchanted items/books.

```
ID is 373
```

I tried variations with potion name, potion effects, effect id and others I found, but nothing worked. With `373` only, it takes all potions, with other tries it takes everything or nothing.

Answer (score -1):

You can't really sort potions as they are unstackable items. But if you are saying to organise them, you can, but it will require a lot of stuff.  Check this link:

Comment: The question is about Craftbook, not vanilla item sorters.

Comment: ... and the link is dead.